# Is there any other way to make the animation look like on the image below?

Tags: animation, rigging

I need advice oh how to make connections in my animation - I think it requires rig, or is there any other way to make the animation look like on the image in the comment below.

All I have for now is a cloud of empties, to which I parented the spheres. I would like to add lines (could use some narrow cylinders maybe) to make the connections, so it would be more clear that these are the human characters, not a bunch of dots.
What would be the EASIEST WAY TO MAKE IT? :slight_smile:[image]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/12rf1zq  - the image (desired look for the animation).

Answer (score 0):

Add a bezier curve, select a sphere, shift select the curve, go to edit mode, select one control point and press Ctrl H (Hook to selected object). Repeat for the other control point and the second sphere.

With geometry property Bevel, you can set the diameter of the link.

[image]